# Old migration fails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have a Rails application which have a lot of migrations. Right now I want to redefine almost all the database structure, so most of those migrations will be useless.

What is the approach that I should take? Modify the existing tables with migrations that modify them, or remove those migrations and create new ones?

Thanks

Comment: I feel a migration should be able to be rolled back aswell as applied.  If you make substantial database structure changes it might make rolling back through these old migrations difficult if not impossible.  If this were the case I would remove them.

Comment: The file db/schema.rb (don't modify this file!!!) is the structure of your DB at the last migration you ran (the file is updated by Rails after each migration). You can eventually erase all migrations and replace them with 1 migration per table (model), and the content would be the content of schema.rb

Comment: Modify the existing tables with migrations that modify them.  Better to have a record of what was done.  If you start to go backward and delete things you could run into problems and be unable to go to a point that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database, if you want to modify your database migrations:

You can update migration file and can do updates on that migration by redoing it:

```
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=001XXXXX
```

To down your existing migration:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=001XXXXX
```

To up specific migration:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=001XXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check in your `schema.rb` to the `VCS`, and you are not seeding the database in your existing migrations, then it's probably ok to delete or archive the old migrations. It is nowhere recommended to create database from migrations anyways. For that you should use the schema.rb only.

Found a nice article on this.

http://adventuresincoding.com/2010/02/how-to-clean-up-your-activerecord-migrations